# Load a new file every day from S3 bucket to Snowflake table

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-s3, snowflake-connector

My Amazon S3 path is as follows:

```
s3://dev-mx-allocation-storage/ph_test_late_waiver/{year}/{month}/{day}/{flow_number}*.csv
```

I need to create a pipeline from S3 to Snowflake where for each day of the month a new csv file would fall into the bucket and that csv file should be inserted into a snowflake table.

I am very new to this, can I please get a command in snowflake which can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Snowpipe lends itself well to real-time requirements of data, as it loads data based on triggers and can manage vast and continuous loading. Data volumes and the compute/storage resources to load data are managed by the Snowflake cloud, which is why it is promoted as a serverless feature. If it’s one less thing to manage, all the better to focus our energies on our own application development!

**Step by step guide**: https://medium.com/@walton.cho/auto-ingest-snowpipe-on-s3-85a798725a69

Comment: I do not have access to Amazon S3, is there any command in snowflake that will allow me to load the data from S3 into snowflake for my use case?

Comment: Without proper authorization to access S3, you won't be able to load any data from S3 to Snowflake.

Comment: For a different use case, where i only had to load 1 csv file from an S3 bucket. I was able to do it with just the AWS key and secret key id, and not required to login into AWS.

Comment: There are 3 options for loading from S3. Details: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-s3-config.html#configuring-secure-access-to-amazon-s3